# Generate dataframe with same key but different value

Tags: pandas

How can I generate a dataframe with common key but different value?

```
import pandas as pd
    
A = {"ID":["A", "B","C"], "Weight":[500,300,200]}
B = {"ID":["A", "B","D"], "Weight":[500,100,100]}

dfA = pd.DataFrame(data=A)
dfB = pd.DataFrame(data=B)

dfC = dfA.merge(dfB, how='outer', left_on=['ID'], right_on=['ID'])
dfC
```

Current output is:

```
  ID  Weight_x  Weight_y
0  A     500.0     500.0
1  B     300.0     100.0
2  C     200.0       NaN
3  D       NaN     100.0
```

But my expected output (ID is common key, so A is identical value but C and D not common element):

```
  ID  Weight_x  Weight_y
0  B     300.0     100.0
```

Comment: How come `C` and `D` doesn't contain a different values or you can considering to negate `nan` values during computation?

Comment: If you have nan values For `Weight` for both dfA and dfB, would they be considered equal?

Comment: I think you want an `inner` merge so that it joins on ID, but then add on a `query` to keep only rows where Weight is different.

Comment: ID  is the key to check common or not, so C and D will be dropped since it not common in both df.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `merge` with the default parameter `how='inner'` as suggested by @ALollz and `query` to keep different `weight` values:

```
>>> pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on='ID').query("Weight_x != Weight_y")

  ID  Weight_x  Weight_y
1  B       300       100
```

Comment: thanks, it's baseon the dfC, any better solution from dfA and dfB directly?

Comment: The solution now is based on dfA and dfB.